# python readline module folder name completion

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cygwin, readline

I am trying to implement a folder name completion for one of my programs and i am using the [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module for it. I have written a Completer class (file `autocompletion.py`):

```
import os.path
import readline


class Completer(object):

    def _match_path(self, text):
        text = readline.get_line_buffer()
        return DirectoryPathCompleter(text).completions()

    def complete(self, text, state):
        matches = self._match_path(text)
        try:
            return matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None


class DirectoryPathCompleter(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def completions(self):
        path, rest = os.path.split(self.text)
        if rest == '.' or rest == '..':
            result = [rest + '/']
        else:
            result = [i + '/' for i in get_dirs_under(path) if i.startswith(rest)]
        return result


def get_dirs_under(path):
    if not path:
        path = '.'
    dirpath, dirnames, filenames = os.walk(path).next()
    return dirnames
```

To try this out here is a little script `try_readline.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from autocompletion import Completer
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.set_completer(Completer().complete)
raw_input('Test it! > ')
```

I can see there, that it works quite good as long as I do not try to complete dirnames that can be completed just partially. When I create for example a directory with the following structure and run the program via shell:

```
$ mkdir -p test/bla-foo test/bla-bar test/bla-baz test/something test/else
$ cp autocompletion.py try_readline.py test
$ cd test; tree
.
├── autocompletion.py
├── bla-bar
├── bla-baz
├── bla-foo
├── else
├── something
└── try_readline.py

5 directories, 2 files

$ python try_readline.py
```

and I try to complete `bla-` via TAB, I get as a result `bla-bla-`. I would like the completion to stick with `bla-` and show the alternatives that can be completed.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I don't know exactly why this is happening. If I alter the `try_readline.py` script to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
raw_input('Test it! > ')
```

So I am not using my own `Completer` and I run it on the same folder structure as shown above, I can see similar behaviour:

```
Test it! > bla-b<TAB>
Test it! > bla-bla-
```

Whereas I would expect:

```
Test it! > bla-b<TAB>
Test it! > bla-ba<TAB><TAB>
bla-bar/ bla-baz/
```

**EDIT2**

Ok I have another approach now, it took so long because the readline documentation is very sparse.. I still don't get exactly why I do have to do it this way but it works.

If I look at the delimiters readline is using, I get:

```
In [1]: readline.get_completer_delims()
Out[1]: ' \t\n`!@#$^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:\'",<>?'
```

Especially the `\\` part looked odd to me, so I did set new delimiters in the `try_readline.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import readline
from autocompletion import Completer

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n')
raw_input('Test it! > ')
```

I am now using the standard readline completion as  I don't know exactly how to write a correct `Completer`... I would like to reuse the standard readline completion function and just filter out any non-directories but I don't know how to extract it from the module.

Comment: It seems like readline isn't available on Max OSX, but for some issues one might use libedit, which isn't installed at my Max. Sorry, then someone else has to help you!

Comment: @holroy Thanks anyway for having a look!